# On hover, text goes over the content with background

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to make, that my text, which is in the table, on hover goes over the content with white background and expand. I got the expand, but I cant get the overflow  over the content. Here is also a JsFiddle of my code: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/8g0kvjx2/1/)

```css
.logon-info-head {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.logon-info-head > div, .logon-info > div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.type{ width: 19%; }
.date-time {width: 20%; }
.country { width: 5%; }
.op-system { width: 18%; }
.browser { width: 12%; }
.ip-address { width: 9%; }

.logon .logon-info{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.op-system, .browser{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.op-system:hover, .browser:hover {
    position: inherit;
    background: white;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logon">
    <div class="logon-info-head">
        <div class="type">Connection type</div>
        <div class="date-time">Connection date and time</div>
        <div class="ip-address">IP address</div>
        <div class="country">Country</div>
        <div class="op-system">Operating system</div>
        <div class="browser">Browser</div>
        <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>
    <div class="logon-info">
        <div class="type">Web application user</div>
        <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
        <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
        <div class="country">US</div>
        <div class="op-system">Linux Ubuntu</div>
        <div class="browser">Google Chrome</div>
        <div class="status">Failed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="logon-info">
        <div class="type">Web application user</div>
        <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
        <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
        <div class="country">LV</div>
        <div class="op-system">Windows XP Professional x64 Edition</div>
        <div class="browser">Mozilla Firefox</div>
        <div class="status">Success</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you instead use the code html/js snippet here instead of jsfiddle?

Comment: you could take a look at transform https://jsfiddle.net/8g0kvjx2/3/ to allow background to be drawn as well

Comment: damn @GCyrillus put that code on answer, I'll accept it. This works for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use transform to allow background to be shown too:

```css
.logon {} .logon .logon-info-head {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.logon .logon-info-head>div,
.logon .logon-info>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
.logon .logon-info>div {} .logon .logon-info-head .type,
.logon .logon-info .type {
  width: 19%
}
.logon .logon-info-head .date-time,
.logon .logon-info .date-time {
  width: 20%
}
.logon .logon-info-head .country,
.logon .logon-info .country {
  width: 5%
}
.logon .logon-info-head .op-system,
.logon .logon-info .op-system {
  width: 18%
}
.logon .logon-info-head .browser,
.logon .logon-info .browser {
  width: 12%
}
.logon .logon-info-head .ip-address,
.logon .logon-info .ip-address {
  width: 9%
}
.logon .logon-info {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.logon .logon-info .op-system,
.logon .logon-info .browser {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.logon .logon-info .op-system:hover,
.logon .logon-info .browser:hover {
  background: white;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  transform: scale(2) translatey(-1em);
  transform-origin: center 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logon">

  <div class="logon-info-head">
    <div class="type">Connection type</div>
    <div class="date-time">Connection date and time</div>
    <div class="ip-address">IP address</div>
    <div class="country">Country</div>
    <div class="op-system">Operating system</div>
    <div class="browser">Browser</div>
    <div class="status">Status</div>
  </div>

  <div class="logon-info">
    <div class="type">Web application user</div>
    <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
    <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
    <div class="country">US</div>
    <div class="op-system">Linux Ubuntu</div>
    <div class="browser">Google Chrome</div>
    <div class="status">Failed</div>
  </div>

  <div class="logon-info">
    <div class="type">Web application user</div>
    <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
    <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
    <div class="country">LV</div>
    <div class="op-system">Windows XP Professional x64 Edition</div>
    <div class="browser">Mozilla Firefox</div>
    <div class="status">Success</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8g0kvjx2/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: pre-wrap;` on `:hover` to show the whole text. This will help you to overflow the content and show the content as well.

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0kvjx2/2/)**

## Edit

Or if you don't want to change the height of the row, you need to make the `width: auto;` on hover.

Just like:

```
.logon .logon-info .op-system:hover,
.logon .logon-info .browser:hover {
  min-width: 18%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but it changes a height of row

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons You need to make the width auto, to let overflow the white color of the background according to the width of actual text. Have a look at my updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the :before pseudo element on the cell divs with the divs having a additional custom attribute `tooltip="cell content"` and use opacity on the :before:hover plus a little bit of make up css to show full text tooltips.

Here is your code with changes to do what you desire.

```css
.logon{}

.logon .logon-info-head{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.logon .logon-info-head>div, .logon .logon-info>div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.logon .logon-info>div{
}

.logon .logon-info-head .type, .logon .logon-info .type{width: 19%}
.logon .logon-info-head .date-time, .logon .logon-info .date-time{width: 20%}
.logon .logon-info-head .country, .logon .logon-info .country{width: 5%}
.logon .logon-info-head .op-system, .logon .logon-info .op-system{width: 18%}
.logon .logon-info-head .browser, .logon .logon-info .browser{width: 12%}
.logon .logon-info-head .ip-address, .logon .logon-info .ip-address{width: 9%}

.logon .logon-info{width: 100%;padding: 5px 0;}

.logon .logon-info .op-system,
.logon .logon-info .browser{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.logon .logon-info .op-system[tooltip]:before,
.logon .logon-info .browser[tooltip]:before{
     position : absolute;
     content : attr(tooltip);
     opacity : 0;
     background: white;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #888888;
     padding:5px;
     }

.logon .logon-info .op-system[tooltip]:hover:before,
.logon .logon-info .browser[tooltip]:hover:before{
    opacity : 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="logon">

    <div class="logon-info-head">
     <div class="type">Connection type</div>
     <div class="date-time">Connection date and time</div>
     <div class="ip-address">IP address</div>
     <div class="country">Country</div>
     <div class="op-system">Operating system</div>
     <div class="browser">Browser</div>
     <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>

    <div class="logon-info">
     <div class="type">Web application user</div>
     <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
     <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
     <div class="country">US</div>
     <div class="op-system" tooltip="Linux Ubuntu">Linux Ubuntu</div>
     <div class="browser" tooltip="Google Chrome">Google Chrome</div>
     <div class="status">Failed</div>
    </div>

    <div class="logon-info">
     <div class="type">Web application user</div>
     <div class="date-time">04.11.2016 13:21:25</div>
     <div class="ip-address">10.195.2.98</div>
     <div class="country">LV</div>
     <div class="op-system" tooltip="Windows XP Professional x64 Edition">Windows XP Professional x64 Edition</div>
     <div class="browser" tooltip="Mozilla Firefox">Mozilla Firefox</div>
     <div class="status">Success</div>
    </div>

   </div>
```